# Sort a list of dictionaries by a key, based on the order of keys in a separate list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting, key

I have a list of dictionaries which looks something like this:

```py
[
    {
        "format": "format1",
        "code": "tr"
    },
    {
        "format": "format2",
        "code": "hc"
    },
    {
        "format": "format3",
        "code": "bx"
    },
    {
        "format": "format4",
        "code": "mm"
    },
    {
        "format": "format5",
        "code": "el"
    }
]
```

I need to order this list based on the value of the code key, but the order of the codes is determined by a separate list:

```py
code_order = ["mm", "hc", "el", "tr", "bx"]
```

So the final list should look like this:

```py
[
    {
        "format": "format4",
        "code": "mm"
    },
    {
        "format": "format2",
        "code": "hc"
    },
    {
        "format": "format5",
        "code": "el"
    },
    {
        "format": "format1",
        "code": "tr"
    },
    {
        "format": "format3",
        "code": "bx"
    }
]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?  I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to do this kind of sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2.7+:

```
lookup = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(code_order)}
print(sorted(l, key=lambda o: lookup[o['code']]))
```

Older:

```
lookup = dict((s, i) for i, s in enumerate(code_order))
print sorted(l, key=lambda o: lookup[o['code']])
```

Comment: To expand John's answer little, creating a lookup dictionary and using it as a sort key is the most efficient and pythonic approach. If you wish to sort the existing list, rather than create a new list then the second line becomes l.sort(key=lambda o: lookup[o['code']]).

Comment: @moreati, in that case I assume it would be better to just start with a lookup dictionary rather than converting code_order from a list to a dict.  I have control over that so that's easy enough to do, in which case I just need the second line.  Perfect.  That is much simpler than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

If `l` is your list of dicts, then

```
sorted(l, key=lambda d: code_order.index(d['code']))
```

should do the trick. Read that as:

> `key` is the function that looks up `code` in the given dict `d`, then checks the index of that code in `code_order`, so the final sort is by those indices.

(If `code_order` gets really large, then keep in mind that `list.index` takes linear time so you'd better replace it by a dict. But for this short `code_order`, it shouldn't matter.)

Comment: Thanks!  I accepted John's answer as it gave the dictionary approach, but thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `person_list` with `name_order` as shown below:

```py
person_list = [
  {'name':'Bob','age':18}, {'name':'Kai','age':36}, {'name':'Ada','age':24} 
]

name_order = ['Kai', 'Ada', 'Bob']

print(sorted(person_list, key=lambda x: name_order.index(x['name'])))
```

Output:

```
[
  {'name':'Kai', 'age':36}, {'name':'Ada', 'age':24}, {'name':'Bob','age':18}
]
```